# printing x number of lines after pattern match

Tags: php, regex

I have a php code which browse through the log files for a pattern. After the pattern is found, I would like to print the next few lines coming after that. Or if we can capture the part till where a specific pattern is encountered.

The contents of the log file would be found like this:

```
DEV   - 2018-07-10 03:10:22 --> --------------API CALL STARTS-------------
DEV   - 2018-07-10 03:10:22 --> ------------------------------------------
DEV   - 2018-07-10 03:10:22 --> -------------------------------------
DEV   - 2018-07-10 03:10:22 --> ----------- HEADERS START ----------------
DEV   - 2018-07-10 03:10:22 -->  
XYZ-DEVICE : XZY 
XYZ-DEVICE : XZY
XYZ-DEVICE : XZY

DEV   - 2018-07-10 03:10:22 --> ----------- HEADERS END ----------------
DEV   - 2018-07-10 03:10:22 --> ----------- API AND PARAMS START ---------------
DEV   - 2018-07-10 03:10:22 --> api.xyz.com/api/abc/xyz_get 
DEV   - 2018-07-10 03:10:22 -->  

DEV   - 2018-07-10 03:10:22 --> ----------- API AND PARAMS END ---------------
DEV   - 2018-07-10 03:10:22 --> -------------------------------------
DEV   - 2018-07-10 03:10:22 --> ------------------------------------------
DEV   - 2018-07-10 03:10:22 --> ---------------API CALL ENDS--------------
```

Ideally I would like to get content from:

```
----------- HEADERS START ----------------
```

till

```
----------- API AND PARAMS END ---------------
```

so i can later use it to make api calls.

My current script finds out the api calls, but it doesn't print out content after the pattern is matched.

```
$dir = "./log/"; 
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        $counter = 1;
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if($file != '.' || $file != '..'){
                $searchfor = 'api.xyz.com/api/'; //pattern to search for

                // the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
                header('Content-Type: text/plain');

                // get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
                $contents = file_get_contents($dir.'/'.$file);
                // escape special characters in the query
                $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
                // finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
                $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
                // search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
                if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
                   echo "Found matches:\n";
                   echo $counter." - ".implode("\n", $matches[0]);
                   echo "\n";
                   $counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need a regex. You can just use `strpos()` for `HEADERS START` and `API AND PARAMS END`

Comment: Thanks for the idea.